# Disable Hardware back button in cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, preventdefault

I know I'm not the first to ask this question, but none of the solutions for the previous questions work.

I'm building a mobile application using Cordova, and I don't want the user to press the hardware back button because it might ruin the whole business scenario. What I need is to disable hardware back button completely from the application in order to allow the user to use only the in app buttons

Thank you

Comment: It could help if you post the solutions that didn't work for you, but anyway did you try this: "document.addEventListener("backbutton", function() { }, false);"?

Comment: @Ness  Yes, I used the following code but it didn't work document.addEventListener('backbutton', function(event) {event.preventDefault();}, false);

Comment: weird, it worked for me on the last cordova app I wrote (which was about 3 months ago). are you sure your function really get called? maybe add a log there just to be sure?

Comment: @Ness I tried to debug it it steps over the preventDefault() method without stopping the back behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Just fetch backbutton response and do prevent default. or do noting in that. That is more than enough to stop backbutton work

```
function onDeviceReady(){
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);     
}
function onBackKeyDown(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Actually I tried this way and it's still doing the default behavior. I tried to debug it it steps over the preventDefault() method without stopping the back behavior.

Comment: in that case check which version of cordova you are using. If you are using older version try update it. It should work

Comment: Alright, I'll try this I hope it'll work... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you have correctly referenced cordova.js.

Sounds a lot like the behaviour when cordova has not been included.