# Disable Back button in Angular4 Cordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova, typescript

I am using Angular 4 on top of Cordova, So I need to disable phone back button in Android. Can anyone share How to disable it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Hardware back button in cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427115/disable-hardware-back-button-in-cordova)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the button event, and do nothing, so it will not go backwards:

```
declare var device;
...
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
  console.log(device);
  if(device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android'){
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
  }

  function onBackKeyDown(){
    console.log("Does nothing");
  }
}
```

Pd: You need to have the plugin cordova-plugin-device installed

Comment: Thanks, I frogot to add cordova.js

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach for this would be to push an initial dummy history entry and then overwrite the window's onpopstate event to always push the dummy entry again. This way, your app will basically do nothing when the user presses the back button.

```
// If using TypeScript:
declare var window:any;    

// In your App Boot function (for example app.component constructor):
window.history.pushState("BackLock", null, "");

window.onpopstate = (evt) => {
    // evt.preventDefault(); might work as an alternative
    window.history.pushState("BackLock", null, "");
    return; 
}
```